# Is there a Windows script to disable & enable the Intel GPU?

Tags: windows, laptop, script, intel-graphics

So I've bought a new laptop with the Intel 4400 GPU. Which I'm trying to connect to an external monitor with hdmi, only the monitor gives me a no signal error.

So I went on Google and found a workaround which is disable the Intel GPU and then re-enable it in devicemanagement. Which surprisingly works so I'm looking now for a Windows script (bat file) which does it for me.

So I'm looking for a script which can disable the Intel GPU and enable it again.

Thank you.

Comment: What is the work around?

Comment: Disabling the Intel GPU and then enable it again.

Comment: How did you disable it. Be specfic.

Comment: Ah oke, in devicemanagement I right click on the Intel GPU and disable it. After waiting till the screen is back on then I enable it again. Wait a few seconds then the external monitor is connected and ready to use.

Comment: Update the question....with that relevant information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if this is possible without any 3rd party tools so here's my approach done with one handy tool from [Nirsoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/).

1. Download [`devmanview.exe`](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/device_manager_view.html), move it to the `system32` folder and run it.
2. Find the specified GPU, right click it and click `Properties`, copy the `Device Name` value and paste it somewhere, because you'll need it later.
   [image: example]
3. Now copy this into Notepad:

```
@echo off
echo *** Restarting GPU ***
devmanview.exe /disable_enable "DeviceName"
echo *** Done ***
pause
```

4. Replace `DeviceName` with the string you've copied earlier keeping the quotes, for example: `devmanview.exe /disable_enable "NVIDIA GeForce 210"`.
5. Save the file with the `.bat` extension somewhere near and that's it.

To reboot the video driver, all you have to do is run this batch file.

<sup>Remember: other applications that depend on the GPU may crash.</sup>

Comment: Thank you for this extensive answer I'll try it out when there are no other options available since I'm a little suspicious of software coming from Nirsoft.

Comment: Ah I tried it out (after some Googling) and it works perfectly and you're about applications relying on the GPU will crash but since I will only run it at boot, that will be no problem! Sorry that I cannot upvote your answer mine reputation isn't high enough.

Comment: @Xepos Glad to help. By the way, Nirsoft has a lot of great tools on their site, never had problems with them.

Comment: Yes I know of Nirsoft I've downloaded quite few security (hacking) tools from there for my security classes. Maybe that's why I'm a little suspicious of it.

Comment: Would be great if this worked for Windows 10 as well.

Comment: @LPChip I just tested this on Windows 10 (made a script that restarts my Wi-Fi network adapter), it works fine.

Comment: Let me test something. I might've tried to run the x64 on an x86 os. and that gave me the wrong error. EDIT: ok, had run the wrong version and Windows 10 does not tell you the correct error anymore. It just says: "This does not run."

Comment: Downloaded the correct version and it works like a charm. +1

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft has a very powerfull command line tool [Windows Device Console (Devcon.exe)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/devcon) which can be used to script the device manager.

Example for enabling / disabling the Intel Graphics:

```
devcon.exe disable "Intel(R) HD Graphics 4400"
devcon.exe enable "Intel(R) HD Graphics 4400"
```